# What is the replacement of AWSLambdaClient

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I am using `AWSLambdaClient.createFunction()`. This got deprecated.

Please let me know, what is the alternative for this.

```
AWSLambdaClient lclient = new AWSLambdaClient(Credentials);
..
..
lclient.createFunction(request);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [AWSLambdaClientBuilder](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/lambda/AWSLambdaClientBuilder.html),

```
BasicAWSCredentials creds = new BasicAWSCredentials("access_key", "secret_key"); 
AWSLambda lClient = AWSLambdaClientBuilder.standard().withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(creds)).build();
```

Comment: @ViswanathAlikonda what is the version of SDK?

Comment: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.amazonaws.util.StringUtils.trim(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
at com.amazonaws.auth.profile.internal.AwsProfileNameLoader.getEnvProfileName(AwsProfileNameLoader.java:72)
at com.amazonaws.auth.profile.internal.AwsProfileNameLoader.loadProfileName(AwsProfileNameLoader.java:54)
at com.amazonaws.regions.AwsProfileRegionProvider.<init>(AwsProfileRegionProvider.java:40)
at com.amazonaws.regions.DefaultAwsRegionProviderChain.<init>(DefaultAwsRegionProviderChain.java:23)
at com.amazonaws.client.builder.AwsClientBuilder.<clinit>(AwsClientBuilder.java:58)

Comment: AWS SDK version 1.11.87

Comment: Strange! The method does exist in the SDK. Could be a version issue, can you try with an alternate version, a latest one and see if it solves.

Comment: Any idea, what is the working version for the fix you suggsted.Later version deprecated many things.

Comment: I took from the latest. [Here](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/master/aws-java-sdk-core/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/util/StringUtils.java#L182) you can see the method do exist.

Comment: After fixing the buildpath, things started working. Thanks.

Comment: @ViswanathAlikonda Can you please explain what exactly you fixed in BuildPath?